# constructor exception (Error: WSE 99999) in SAP BusinessObjects Analysis Edition for Microsoft Office

Tags: java, excel, excel-2010, business-objects

In our company we have started using SAP BusinessObjects Analysis Edition for Microsoft Office (Version: 2.1.1.10239) for Microsoft Office 2010. But from past few days I have started getting the following error message while logging into Analysis Edition for Microsoft Office:

> constructor exception (Error: WSE 99999)

When I contacted our Tech support, they were saying that ***"It is an error in the Java code that handles the connection between your AAO Add-in in Excel and the BOE server (Web Service)"***

I have reinstalled Java 8 Update 66 and also reinstalled Analysis Edition for Microsoft Office, but still I am getting that error.  I am  also attaching error screenshot for your reference.

Please help me to fix this problem.

I have tried all possible options before posting this question here. I have been trying to fix this from past 4 days and I couldn't succeed :(

[image]

Comment: This is unrelated to the Java installed locally, as AAO is .NET technology. The only place where Java comes into play here, is on the server. Thus, you can dismiss the JRE installation from the equation. Best would be to enable debug logging in AAO's properties and use something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to debug the HTTP calls between your client and the server to see what's happening. Also, `dswsbobje` debugging (on the server) might help clarify the issue.

Comment: I am not sure how to do the "dswsbobje" debugging on the server.  Could you please let me know in detail (step by step)?  Thanks

Comment: Have a look at SAP note [1668106](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1668106) on how to set up logging for `dswsbobje`. The note is for XI3 but it applies to BI4 as well. You'll need an SAP Support account to access the note though.